# Change properties of a style's paragraph with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following style:

```
#menu-content p
{
font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
font-variant: small-caps;
font-size: 2.5vmin;
font-weight: 100;
}
```

How would I go about changing e.g. the font weight with jquery? The syntax of the call is unclear to me. Would it be

```
$("#menu-content p").css ("font-weight", "150");
```

or

```
$("#menu-content").$("p").css ("font-weight", "150");
```

I tried both; neither seemed to work.

Comment: It will be `"#menu-content p"` almost all CSS selectors work fine in jQuery.

Comment: The first one is correct.  Why it's not working is impossible to say with what you've posted.  Create a snippet to show it failing.

Comment: [The documentation is pretty clear...](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2)

Comment: Firstly, http://learn.jquery.com is great for beginners. I'd suggest you familiarise yourself with selector logic. Secondly, your first example should work fine. I'd guess you've not included a document.ready event handler if it's not working for you, or possibly that it is working but the difference from a weight of 100 to 150 will not change anything. Try settin g `600` instead. Thirdly, use classes where possible, over direct `css()` injection

Comment: Isn't the reason neither of your solutions seem to work that no current browser is able to render the difference between `font-weight` 100 and 150 ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change it so something that has a [visible effect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight) - then your first call is correct assuming the accessed elements exists in the page at the time of the call:

```js
$(function() { // when page has loaded - you might have missed this 
  setTimeout(function() { // just for the demo
    $("#menu-content p").css ("font-weight", "550"); 
    $("#menu-content p").html("Now font-weight: 550")
  },2000);
});
```

```css
#menu-content p {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-size: 10vmin 1rem;
  font-weight: 100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Wait 2 secs
<div id="menu-content"><p>Initial font-weight: 100</p></div>
```

Answer (score -3):

You can only change the id as it's unique:

```
$("#menu-content").css("font-weight", "150");
```